# I'm new to React-Native and i was trying to move from one screen to another after a button is clicked

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

Error i receive when i try to navigate to another screen

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

You can find the whole project here:

https://snack.expo.io/@nadamabrouk/mobile-flash-cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DeckList.js you need to pass the navigation to the child prop

```
{Object.values(entries).map((entry, index) => {
          return (
            <DeckDetail
              navigation={this.props.navigation}
              key={index}
              entry={entry}
            />
          );
})}
```

and in the onPress handler it should be DeckView instead of Deckview

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DeckView")}
```